# map then forEach returning expected assignment or function call React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that is mapping then running a forEach to return a result. this function works fine in a plain js html file. but in React im getting the expected assignment or function call error

Here is the code

```
const customContactValues = fiftyContacts?.map((contact) => { 
    let result = {};
  // this line is giving error  
mentionReformat?.forEach((mention) => { result[mention.name] = valueByKey(contact, mention.name) } ); return result
});
```

Comment: Please give more context. Show your error too.

Comment: I needed to assign the mentionReformat as const test = mentionReformat....

Comment: show the error msg too

Comment: may be because the mentionReformat is null? what error? May be use map too? THe first map should return contact instead of result by modify.